# MySQL error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql

Error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' WHERE username=32112' at line 1

PHP code:

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM '$iAccount_table' WHERE username=$user") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: 1) Table names are enclosed in `\``, not in `'`
2) Be sure to triple-check what your variable contains (keyword: sql injection) or better yet: Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that 'username' is a text/char field in your db. Try this code:

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM " . $iAccount_table . " WHERE username='" . $user . "'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`** instead of **'** with the $iAccount_table variable. Its erroring out because of that.

Update:

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `$iAccount_table` WHERE username=$user") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM '$iAccount_table' WHERE username=$user") or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `$iAccount_table` WHERE username=$user") or die(mysql_error());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use back ticks (grave accent) ` instead of single quotes so

```
"SELECT * FROM `$iAccount_table` WHERE username=$user"
```